# Use affected file/directory to streamread to console

Tags: c#, .net, backend

I'm trying to actively scan recent file inputs from a directory and `StreamReading` the file to console. I'm having problems finding a solution to using the most recent file input and printing the whole file text lines to console. I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` for recent inputs.

Here's my code (I'm a beginner):

```
private static void filesys_created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "    : New file input: {0}", e.Name + Enviroment.Newline);

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(directorypath))
        {
            string path = directorypath
            String line = sr.ReadLine(e.Name);
            string filename = e.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    catch (exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File could not be read to console");
    }
}
```

Only error showing is "No overload for method "ReadLine" takes 1 argument.

& File is not streamreading text to console

Comment: For information : the errror you have is a compilation error, so your code won't execute.

And for information N° 2, on Stack Overflow you can format your code by selecting your code and click the "code formatting" button (which basically adds  4 spaces in front of the lines) to show it in a nice way. I edited your question to fix the format, you can check how it looks if you want. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must open the file from `FullPath` in `FileSystemEventArgs`

Then, you can write to console the content of the file by `ReadToEnd`

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
{
     Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```